# HTML validator returns "document type does not allow element "script" here"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I was playing a little bit with jQuery. I'we done everything ok, and it works fine(i'm trying to make my own plugin) with no bugs. But when i try to validate page using [http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) i get 1 error: **document type does not allow element "script" here.**

I have no idea what have i done wrong. Here is my html(js is not important here i guess):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Admin</title>

    <!-- Load jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Document-Load.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='css/iG_Style.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That markup works perfectly fine when validating through Direct Input. Are you sure this sample reproduces your problem correctly?

Comment: Ditto...it works just fine for me as well.

Comment: "Tritto"...works for me, and I tried direct and file upload.

Comment: Perhaps the only error is the one that you stripped as "not important here"?

Comment: yea maybe true..but why should js cause such and error?

Comment: 1) Start with the full code to see if it shows the issue. 2) Try to remove something. 3) does it still show the issue? 3a) If not, do you know what is the problem? 3a1) If yes, you are done. 3a2) If not, reverse the change and go to 2. 3b) If the issue still shows, go to 2.

Comment: Could your server be attaching some script to the end? Some analytics or advertisement maybe?

Comment: Is this what the browser sends?

Comment: Does your script contain the text `<script>` by any means?

Comment: ok, i see now, server attaching some script at the end of the body? does this causing error?

Comment: Show us the code that the server sends

Comment: Ok guys, that's it...that attached script causing error in this case. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent problems testing on the w3c validator, for best practices use the script tag before the body as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Admin</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='css/iG_Style.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body"></div>
  <!-- Load jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Document-Load.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Strict!**